# reactjs conditional statement inside TableCell

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

How do I input conditional if else statement in a TableCell for ReactJS. I want the data table to output nothing is found if the search box returns nothing.

Here is the code:

```
export default function DataTable () {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('') 

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

    useEffect( function () {
        const fetchUsers = async function () {
            const response = await axios.get(`/search/?query=${query}`)
            setTableData(response.data)
        }
     if (query.length === 0 || query.length > 2) fetchUsers()
    }, [query])
   
     
  return (  
    <>
      
        <input type={'text'} placeholder={'Enter Teacher ID Number....'} className='search-bar' onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)} /> 
        <TableContainer component={Paper} className='data-table'>
                <Table sx={{minWidth: 650}} aria-label='simple table'>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>ID</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Surname</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Title</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Email</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Action #1</TableCell>
                            <TableCell className='tableCell'>Action #2</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                    { tableData.map((data) => (
                            <TableRow key={data.id} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border:0}}}>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { data.id }</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { data.name }</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { data.surname }</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { data.title }</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { data.email}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'>
                                    <button className={'verify'}>
                                        <Link to={`/search/${data.id}`} className={'verify'} state={data}>Verify</Link>
                                    </button>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell className='tableCell'>
                                    <button className={`drop`}>
                                        <Link to={`/drop/${data.id}`} className={'drop'} state={data}>Drop</Link>
                                    </button>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                         ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>

    </>
    )
}
```

I tried to input ternary operator '?' but it returns the first result

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend to you separate the mapped Row in a separated component to handle easily and get the code more readable. This component could be in other file.

On the other hand I highly recommend if you are consuming the data from rest service, is using [React Query.](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview)

```
export default function DataTable () {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState('') 

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

    useEffect( function () {
        const fetchUsers = async function () {
            const response = await axios.get(`/search/?query=${query}`)
            setTableData(response.data)
        }
     if (query.length === 0 || query.length > 2) fetchUsers()
    }, [query])

    function UserTableRow(user){
        return (
            <TableRow key={user.id} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {border:0}}}>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { user.id }</TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { user.name }</TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { user.surname }</TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { user.title }</TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'> { user.email}</TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'>
                    <button className={'verify'}>
                        <Link to={`/search/${user.id}`} className={'verify'} state={data}>Verify</Link>
                    </button>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className='tableCell'>
                    <button className={`drop`}>
                        <Link to={`/drop/${user.id}`} className={'drop'} state={data}>Drop</Link>
                    </button>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        )
    }
   
     
  return (  
    <>
      
        <input type={'text'} placeholder={'Enter Teacher ID Number....'} className='search-bar' onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)} /> 
        <TableContainer component={Paper} className='data-table'>
            <Table sx={{minWidth: 650}} aria-label='simple table'>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>ID</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Surname</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Title</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Email</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Action #1</TableCell>
                        <TableCell className='tableCell'>Action #2</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                { tableData?.map((user) => <UserTableRow user={user}/>)}
                {!tableData.length && <div>No results found.</div>}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried that method, it works but only the buttons show up, not the data. Am I doing something wrong!?